Changing angular.json builder from browser to application results in a 404 error
When updating an Angular project from version 17 to 18, automatic changes were made to my angular.json file.
In the "build" section, these changes include:
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" => "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application"
"outputPath": "dist" => "outputPath": {"base": "dist"}
"main": "src/main.ts" => "browser": "src/main.ts"
When running a Docker container on localhost, I get "webpage not found for the web address" and an error 404.
I was able to fix this by making an addition to the outputPath as so: "outputPath": {"base": "dist", "browser": ""}.
Why does this fix the 404 error? What is the difference between application and browser for the builder? And is this a valid solution to my problem?
